# Клиент для сервера по протоколу WebSocket

Tags: javascript, сервер, websocket

Появилась задача: написать, используя javascript, клиент для сервера, который будет постоянно обрабатывать бинарный код, полученный с сервера (сервер будет передавать видеопоток), и трансформировать его в видео, которое, в свою очередь, будет размещено на html-страничке в браузере.

Ясное дело, что сервер, как и клиент, должны общаться по WebSocket-протоколу, чтобы передача видео была постоянной.

Клиентом будет выступать html-страница, с подключенным javascript-скриптом, в котором и будет прописана вся логика.

Так как с javascript никогда не работал, до конца не ясно, как это все дело обрабатывать и вообще провернуть, есть ли какие-нибудь идеи? В интернете информацию не нашел, может, и искал неверно.

Спасибо.

Comment: Может, вы искали **javascreept**, а надо было искать **javascript**?

Comment: Нда, залагал немного, но нет, проблема, конечно, не в этом)

Comment: Какого рода видеопоток отдает сервер? Это лайф данные или из файла? Почему не использовать тег *video*?

Comment: Данные с камеры кодируются сервером в бинарный код для повышения фпс и стабильности, и уже передает клиенту
Насколько я знаю, тег video работает медленнее

Comment: Какая кодировка? Давайте, вы все детали укажите сразу в вопросе) Распишите проблему как можно детальнее.